# Can maven always download package from remote repository, event the package's version is not update, and not snapshot version?

Tags: maven, jar, repository

The problem we meet is:

In the company's private maven center repository, somebody update a jar, but do not update the maven version, and it's not a snapshot version.

So the programs depend on this jar will always use the old jar in local repository, unless we delete local jar by hands.

Can we setup the maven config(local or center) to make maven always download the jar with specific groupId pattern, like com.jd.* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set 'updatePolicy' to 'always' for your repository in settings.xml (see: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-settings/settings.html)

or

`mvn clean install -U`

Comment: thanks, the command' mvn clean install -U' takes effect in maven 2.x, but doesn't work with maven 3.x, could you give me some suggestion. I have search on this for days~~  T_T

Comment: It doesn't work for releases and it shouldn't - released jars shouldn't change. If your company uses e.g. 5.01, 5.0.2.. 5.x.x and publishes updates each build, it should switch to snapshots and release only the stable versions - it guarantees consistency and less 'surprises' during compile time and runtime.